# How to mix many distributions in one tensorflow probability layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I have several `DistributionLambda` layers as the outputs of one model, and I would like to make a Concatenate-like operation into a new layer, in order to have only one output that is the mix of all the distributions, assuming they are independent. Then, I can apply a log-likelihood loss to the output of the model. Otherwise, I cannot apply the loss over a `Concatenate` layer, because it lost the `log_prob` method. I have been trying with the `Blockwise` distribution, but with no luck so far.

Here an example code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow_probability import distributions
from tensorflow_probability import layers as tfp_layers


def likelihood_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """Adding negative log likelihood loss."""
    return -y_pred.log_prob(y_true)


def distribution_fn(params):
    """Distribution function."""
    return distributions.Normal(
        params[:, 0], math.log(1.0 + math.exp(params[:, 1])))


output_steps = 3
...
lstm_layer = layers.LSTM(10, return_state=True)
last_layer, l_h, l_c = lstm_layer(last_layer)
lstm_state = [l_h, l_c]
dense_layer = layers.Dense(2)
last_layer = dense_layer(last_layer)
last_layer = tfp_layers.DistributionLambda(
    make_distribution_fn=distribution_fn)(last_layer)
output_layers = [last_layer]
# Get output sequence, re-injecting the output of each step
for number in range(1, output_steps):
    last_layer = layers.Reshape((1, 1))(last_layer)
    last_layer, l_h, l_c = lstm_layer(last_layer, initial_state=lstm_states)
    # Storing state for next time step
    lstm_states = [l_h, l_c]
    last_layer = tfp_layers.DistributionLambda(
        make_distribution_fn=distribution_fn)(dense_layer(last_layer))
    output_layers.append(last_layer)

# This does not work
# last_layer = distributions.Blockwise(output_layers)

# This works for the model but cannot compute loss
# last_layer = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(output_layers)
the_model = models.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[last_layer])
the_model.compile(loss=likelihood_loss, optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001))
```

Comment: Have a look at tdf.independent. That might work.

Comment: I see `Independent` more like a way to separate distributions into independent pieces. It is related, but what I would like to do is to mix many distributions (a list of them) into one. `Blockwise` seems to work, I changed the commented lines to `last_layer = tfp_layers.DistributionLambda(make_distribution_fn=distributions.Blockwise)(output_layers)`, but now I cannot save the model: [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1183)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Input, not your output layer ;)

Input:0 is referenced in your error message.
Could you try to be more specific about your input?

Comment: The error message is not referring to the input of the whole model, it seems to refer to the first input of the internal `JointDistributionSequential` model that is being created when saving the model.